# php pass arguments to method

Tags: php, methods, arguments

I have the following code :

```
$o_search = new ObjectSearch();
$o_search -> user = $user;
$o_search -> date =':"2012"';
$o_search -> chtype = 'created';
echo "Changetype: " . $o_search -> chtype . "<br/>\n";
echo "User: " .  $o_search -> user . "<br/>\n" ;
echo "Date: " . $o_search -> date  . "<br/>\n"  ;
$result = $o_search->search($o_search->chtype , $o_search->user , $o_search->date);
```

The last line is where I'm having trouble. Whats the correct syntax to pass those arguments to 'search' method?. If I replace those arguments with valid string the code works.
Next is objectSearch class:

```
include_once(__CA_LIB_DIR__."/ca/Search/BaseSearch.php");
include_once(__CA_LIB_DIR__."/ca/Search/ObjectSearchResult.php");

class ObjectSearch extends BaseSearch {
        # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
        /**
         * Which table does this class represent?
         */
        protected $ops_tablename = "ca_objects";
        protected $ops_primary_key = "object_id";
        # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
        public function &search($ps_search, $pa_options=null) {
                return parent::doSearch($ps_search, new ObjectSearchResult(), $pa_options);
        }
        # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: that all depends on the method signature for search.... can you post the method definition for that?

Comment: `$o_search->search($o_search->chtype , $o_search->user , $o_search->date)` looks like duplication because all arguments originate from `$o_search`

Comment: Should I use $this->something instead? I tried but didn't work

Comment: @Orangepill I edited the post and added tne method definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is embarrassing, it was as simple as typing it right...

$result = $o_search->search( $o_search->chtype. ".". $o_search->user. '.:"' . $o_search->date . '"' );

I had to add the punctuation in the right places.
Hope this helps someone.